# How to get the pixels from a geotiff file in gdal python for a given polygon?

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I use python and GDAL under apache to make a webservice.

I have a GeoTIFF file and i want only a subset of the data, everything inside one polygon defined by a buffer of a line (coord is the input parameter of the service):

```
line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
for i in range(len(coord)):
    line.AddPoint(coord[i][0], coord[i][1])

line.Transform(coordTransform)    
polygon = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
polygon = line.Buffer(10.0, 2)
```

I find only solutions with shapefile, not with programmatically created geometries. Any help?

Comment: solved with:
points = []
pixels = []
pts = polygon.GetGeometryRef(0)
for p in range(pts.GetPointCount()):
    points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
for p in points:
    pixels.append(world2Pixel(geoTrans, p[0], p[1]))

Comment: if that solved your questions please post it as an answer and accept it (little tick on the left). This way others with the same problem can easier find the solution in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved with:

```
[...]    
srcArray = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(rasterFile)

pxWidth = int(lrX - ulX)
pxHeight = int(lrY - ulY)

points = []
pixels = []
pts = poligono.GetGeometryRef(0)
for p in range(pts.GetPointCount()):
    points.append((pts.GetX(p), pts.GetY(p)))
for p in points:
    pixels.append(conf.world2Pixel(geoTrans, p[0], p[1]))

for i in range(len(pixels)):
    pixels[i] = (pixels[i][0]-ulX, pixels[i][1]-ulY)

rasterPoly = Image.new("L", (pxWidth, pxHeight), 0)
rasterize = ImageDraw.Draw(rasterPoly)
rasterize.polygon(pixels, 1)
mask = conf.imageToArray(rasterPoly)

valTiff = []
for r in range(pxHeight):
    for c in range(pxWidth):
        if mask[r][c]==1:
            valTiff.append(srcArray[r+ulY][c+ulX])
```